# Polymer-Dart Equivalent Functions

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to work through a Google I/O codelab for the Material Design Web App, but port it to the Dart language.  http://io2014codelabs.appspot.com/static/codelabs/polymer-build-mobile/#4

I'm at the step where you toggle the drawer, but I can't figure out the dart equivalent.

The JS code to toggle the drawer looks like this:

```js
<script>
  Polymer('codelab-app', {
    toggleDrawer: function() {
      this.$.drawerPanel.togglePanel();
    }
  });
</script>
```

I have tried the following in my CodelabApp class, but I get a `NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'togglePanel'`

```dart
@CustomTag('codelab-app')
class CodelabApp extends PolymerElement {
  CodelabApp.created() : super.created() {}
  void toggleDrawer() {
    querySelector('core-drawer-panel')..togglePanel();
  }
}
```

my button element properly fires, but I can't figure out how to call the drawer's togglePanel method.  `<paper-icon-button icon="menu" on-click="{{toggleDrawer}}"></paper-icon-button>`

any help or direction to the proper docs would be greatly appreciated.

### UPDATE:

This has been fixed in recent versions: https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/issues/39

Updating the polymer and core_elements libraries works as expected.

Comment: Can you check in the debugger what type the value is that `querySelector('core-drawer-panel')` returns? `$['drawerPanel']` should work in Dart too if the element has the id `drawerPanel`.
You can try `($['drawerPanel'] as CoreDrawerPanel).togglePanel()`

Comment: Thanks +Günter Zöchbauer.. That seems to get me a little closer, but I still get an `Exception: Class 'CoreDrawerPanel' has no instance method 'togglePanel'`

Comment: I haven't used the new core-elements. I just try it and I'll post an update when I know more.

Comment: Thanks! Here is a repo of the codelab so far: https://github.com/madisona/polymer-dart-material-design-codelab  I'm currently working in the `step4` part

Comment: I'm sure this is a bug in core-drawer-panel. It is missing a redirection to JavaScript method like for example in core_animation.dart (`void cancel() =>
      jsElement.callMethod('cancel', []);`)
I created an issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/issues/39

Comment: Oh bummer... thanks for your help and for filing the issue!

Comment: I have noticed that your imports are fragile. AFAIK this doesn't work when building to JS (https://github.com/madisona/polymer-dart-material-design-codelab/blob/master/web/step4/codelab-app.html) In your example the imports should look like `<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/paper_elements/roboto.html">` you need `../` to go up to the directory containing `pubspec.yaml` and then go down using the `packages` directory. This works in Dart because your `code4` folder contains a symlink to `packages` but this symlink is not available when built to JS and will be removed in Dart too.

Comment: ah man I just ran into the same issue whilst attempting build a demo for someone. I really want to use dart for future projects, and was hoping to mock together a prototype very quickly using the core- and paper-elements. Do any of you know of a temporary workaround?

Comment: Found a temporary workaround that may solve this for you. Submitted as answer

Answer (score 3):

While attempting to commit my own fix to this, I discovered a temporary workaround that works in my case. Maybe will work for you :)

Add the following to the top of your file:

```dart
import 'dart:js' show JsObject;

_js(x) => new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(x);
```

Then change your custom tag code:

```dart
@CustomTag('codelab-app')
class CodelabApp extends PolymerElement {
  CodelabApp.created() : super.created() {}
  void toggleDrawer() {
    _js(shadowRoot.querySelector('core-drawer-panel')).callMethod('togglePanel');
  }
}
```

For reference I found this solution by reading through the code here:
https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/blob/master/example/core_drawer_panel.html#L68-L81