# Listen to click event of core-drawer-panel with polymer.dart the "right" way?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have this core-drawer-panel and want the #navicon to toggle the drawer. Like in the examples.

Using on-click in the HTML and the following code in the dart file, I get a NoSuchMethod Error on the panel

```dart
  void toggleDrawer() {
    querySelector('#drawerPanel')..togglePanel();
  }
```

Now I read that on-click is [somewhat deprecated](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/improving-the-dom/#events) and I'm totally confused.

What is the best practice way to query elements and catch events like this one? I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509067/polymer-dart-equivalent-functions) as well, but it's still not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on-tap` instead of `on-click` provides better support on mobile platforms. `on-tap` 'includes' `on-click`.
See also [Touch & gestures](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/touch.html) and [When to use on-click or on-tap w/ Polymer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386369)

You probably need `shadowRoot.querySelector(...`.

Comment: Danke Günter! ;) Can you explain why I need shadowRoot.querySelector? And is the on-click in my HTML the way to go with dart or is there a better approach?

Comment: Without `shadowRoot` you call `querySelector` on `this` which queries children of your element (placed within the `<content></content>` tag or your element at runtime) but you want to query the internal markup of your element which is in the shadow DOM.

Answer (score 1):

See Günters answer first. Other than that, I found out how to do it like the [article on dartlang.org](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/improving-the-dom/#events) suggests.

HTML

```dart
<core-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel">

        <core-header-panel drawer>
            <core-toolbar id="navheader'">
                <span>Menu</span>
            </core-toolbar>
            <core-menu>
                <core-item label="One"></core-item>
                <core-item label="Two"></core-item>
            </core-menu>
        </core-header-panel>

        <core-header-panel main>
            <core-toolbar id="mainheader">
                <paper-icon-button id="navicon" icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
                <span flex>Title</span>
            </core-toolbar>
            <div class="content">
                If drawer is hidden, press button to display drawer.
            </div>
        </core-header-panel>

    </core-drawer-panel>
```

Dart File

```dart
  void attached() {
    super.attached();
    shadowRoot.querySelector('#navicon').on['tap'].listen(
        (event) => toggleDrawer()
    );
  }

  void toggleDrawer() {
    shadowRoot.querySelector('#drawerPanel')..togglePanel();
  }
```

Comment: It is good to know that this way works and it is useful in some situations, for example when you dynamically want to add/remove listeners but usually it is preferred to set up event listeners declaratively. When you have a huge amount of elements where you register event listeners individually you might benchmark if imperatively added event listeners are faster.